# Circular dependency error in angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular-fullstack

Always I'm getting warning that is circular dependency

```
WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
src\app\auth\logout\logout.component.ts -> src\app\auth\_services\authentication.service.ts -> src\app\app.module.ts -> src\app\app-routing.module.ts ->
src\app\auth\logout\logout.component.ts

WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
src\app\theme\layouts\header-nav\header-nav.component.ts -> src\app\_services\data\emp.service.ts -> src\app\app.module.ts -> src\app\theme\layouts\layout.module.ts -> src\app\theme\layouts\header-nav\header-nav.component.ts

WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
src\app\theme\layouts\layout.module.ts -> src\app\theme\layouts\header-nav\header-nav.component.ts -> src\app\_services\data\emp.service.ts -> src\app\app.module.ts -> src\app\theme\layouts\layout.module.ts

WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
src\app\theme\theme-routing.module.ts -> src\app\auth\_guards\auth.guard.ts -> src\app\auth\_services\user.service.ts -> src\app\app.module.ts -> src\app\theme\theme-routing.module.ts
```

I used this then it was solved

```
"build": {
      "showCircularDependencies": false
    },
```

but how to solve this issue, without using `"showCircularDependencies": false`

Comment: Do you know what a circular dependency is?

Comment: Yes, but I’m using the formal way of integration with the services

Comment: Which exact version of angular are you using?

Comment: you should solve those instead of hidding them

Comment: check your imports across affected files - as warning says you have some circular dependencies in your components and by settings showCircularDependencies to "false" you just hide the warning, but to solve the issue completely you need to change your imports.

Comment: okay but I'm following the standard way of integration. the similar way is not showing any warnings in other project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess there's just no way around it.
You probably would be able to escape this by breaking up one of these `services` into new a `service` and carefully include them.

Take a look at [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). It's the solid way of evading such issues.

Comment: I’m using Angular 5